# Javascript hide div and show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show

I'm making a quiz and I want to hide questions when there not being asked. But I keep getting the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null.

```js
document.getElementById("score").style.display = "none";
```

```html
<!--This is the questions,score and submit button -->
<div id="score">
  <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10"> 
<input type="text" name="textfield" id="textscore">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That error implies that the element with an id of `score` is not in the DOM when you try to hide it. You're probably running your code before the page is ready. Try placing your `<script>` block right before the `</body>` tag

Comment: Exactly make sure you're calling your javascript after the DOM is loaded. if your javascript is in the <head> section of the document, move it to the bottom of the <body> or use DOMContentLoaded event or jQuery's document.ready() method.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan why do you post the answer as a comment? I would have liked to upvote it. ;)

Comment: @PDXIII haha :) I only posted that as a comment because it's not a concrete answer. Sure, it's most likely the problem, but OP hasn't given us enough information to say for certain

Comment: @Rory McCrossan your comment was correct thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the element is in the DOM when you try to hide.

```
document.onreadystatechange = () => {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    // document ready
    document.getElementById("score").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line should be after the html element score.

```
document.getElementById("score").style.display = "none";
```

Or put this line inside a function and call it after the html load
Or as @arpad answered https://stackoverflow.com/a/44139647/20126 do it in the document ready.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
     <title>Solve Type Error</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div id="score">
       <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">   
           <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textscore">
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>

     <script>
        document.getElementById("score").style.display = "none";
     </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this should solve the error. your script tag should be inside your body tag, if you are not using an external link js file.